# How to round values between -1 and 0 up to 0 in a column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements, rounding

I am working with some data in R and I want to change some of the data in  a column in my dataframe. Let's call this column "plasma" and there are tons of positive values, but also quite a few negative ones as well. I don't want to worry about the values that are even more negative than -1 for now.

Instead, before I deal with those unusual values, I'd like to first round any value in the plasma column between -1 and 0 up to 0.

How would I accomplish this? Thank you for any help!

I'm quite new to code and I'm sure I can find something online about making negative values into zero, but I'm less sure about specifying that between a range of numbers changing those values to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
p <- mydf$plasma
mydf$plasma <- ifelse(p>=(-1) & p<0, 0, p)
```

Comment: "Technically,"  :-)  the OP wants    `ifelse( p >=(-1) ...`

Comment: Doesn't that depend on what they mean precisely by "between" ?

Comment: and also  "dont worry about ...values ... more negative than -1"

Answer (score 2):

An approach using `ceiling` at matching positions.

```
pos <- with(dat, plasma < 0 & plasma >= -1)

dat$plasma[pos] <- ceiling(dat$plasma[pos])

dat
      plasma
1  -2.074030
2  -2.185377
3   1.069302
4  -1.652238
5   0.000000
6   0.000000
7  -1.182942
8   1.826667
9   0.000000
10 -1.025324
```

##### Data

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(plasma = (0.5-runif(10))*5)
```